# Intellij uses DevMode class instead of CodeServer

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to start GWT super dev mode from within Intellij. The output tells that Intellij uses `DevMode` class to start super dev mode.

Starting from 2.7 (or even 2.6), there is another class `CodeServer`, which has slightly different arguments. That's why when I try to pass `-launcherDir` it complains `Unknown argument: -launcherDir`.

Is there any way to force Intellij to use the `CodeServer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevMode will call CodeServer, it'll pass the `-war` argument value to CodeServer as `-launcherDir`.

Comment: thank you Thomas, what about `-src` argument, is there also alternative?

Comment: You just add the sources to the classpath.